# Код 302 при авторизации и перенаправлении на другую страницу при первом запуске браузера

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Когда я ввожу данные форму(account/login/) и отправляю их, в терминале пишет

[19/Jun/2020 21:57:10] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 629

[19/Jun/2020 21:57:25] "POST /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Также сама страница, на которую я перенаправляюсь никак не может загрузиться. Перенаправление должно быть на главную страницу '/'.

Если я снова попробую ввести данные, то меня сразу перенаправят на нужную страницу. В общем, эта проблема возникает, если я перезагружу браузер(у меня Google Chrome). Когда я попробовал авторизоваться в Edge, все прошло с первого раза.

Вот мой код:

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import login_view, logout_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
]
```

accounts/forms:

```
from django import forms

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

accounts/views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

from accounts.forms import UserLoginForm

def login_view(request):
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        login(request, user=user)
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

profile/urls(тут указывается главная страница, на которую я хочу попасть):

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import tape

urlpatterns = [
    path('', tape, name='tape')
]
```

profile/views(тут функция, обрабатывающая запрос на нужную страницу):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def tape(request):
    return render(request, 'profile/tape.html')
```

settings(настройки проекта):

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'l&bkoa7xan53kgacy*4ep#ohr+xi$(9n_wg)mc9k&sh!%o-72)'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'profile',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Test.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Test.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MyUser'
```

urls(urls проекта):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include(('accounts.urls', 'accounts'))),
    path('', include(('profile.urls', 'profile')))
]
```

**Как решить эту проблему?**